# flight offer search not pulling all air fares

Tags: python-3.x, amadeus

I would like to seek help on the codes below.

Apparently, the code works by pulling out air fares but it seems like it does not pull out all the available air fares that I can see directly from the airlines websites.

Could anyone please assist me to let me know what's happening? Thanks!

```py
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError

Origin = "SIN"
Destination = "CDG"

amadeus = Client(hostname='production', client_id='HIDDEN', client_secret='HIDDEN')

try:
    '''
    Find the cheapest flights from Origin to Destination
    '''
    response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers_search.get(
        #originLocationCode=Origin, destinationLocationCode=Destination, departureDate='2023-04-04', adults=1)
        originLocationCode=Origin, destinationLocationCode=Destination, departureDate='2023-03-03', returnDate='2023-04-04', travelClass='BUSINESS', includedAirlineCodes='SQ', currencyCode='SGD', adults=1)
    print(response.data)

except ResponseError as error:
    raise error
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question about the code shown, but about a third-party API. Scheduled flights are an extremely complex product. You need to talk to your account manager at Amadeus about what flights are available to you, and what's the most appropriate type of search for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The Self-Service APIs only return public fares coming from the GDS. That means that you will find discrepancy for both the flights and the prices too comparing to some websites you might visit.

For more details check the section [carriers and rates](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/resources/flights/#carriers-and-rates) in the developer guides.